# Problem with JSONValue

Tags: java, json, json-simple

Am I totally missing something here?  Why can't I get out what I'm putting in?

```
Set<String> stringSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
stringSet.add("firstName");
Map<String,Object> payload = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
payload.put("properties", stringSet);

String sPayload = JSONValue.toJSONString(payload);
payload = (Map<String, Object>) JSONValue.parse(sPayload); // <-- payload == NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) bug (as of version 1.1) -- it doesn't know how to convert a `Set` into a JSON array, so it ends up just calling `toString()` on it and inserting the results verbatim.

As a result, your JSON looks like:

```
{"properties":[firstName]}
```

Which causes `JSONValue.parse()` to choke on the unquoted `firstName`.

If you use a `List` it works properly:

```
{"properties":["firstName"]}
```

There's an open issue about this problem: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/issues/detail?id=23

Comment: Or you can trick it by adding quotes for the firstName ^^ stringSet.add("\"firstName\"");